# How do I generate a word list from a known seed word?

Tags: passwords, keepass, dictionary

I've lost my master password. Not all is lost as I know the original word that generated the password: It was generated by a random case switching for consonants and random vocal to numbers. For instance: `a` and `A` become `4`.

I'm searching online for list generators that takes the seed word and generates permutations as I've described. I yet have to find a solution.

Does someone know a generator that matches my requirement, or do I have no other option than to make my own word list?

Answer (score 2):

I recently created a tool called [PassGen](https://github.com/Broham/PassGen) that will do what you are talking about.  It basically takes a target words and generates a password list using common substitutions.

A basic example:

```
python passgen.py -f forgot
```

will generate 1024 passwords as shown below:

```
forgot
forgoT
forgo+
forgo7
.
.
.
FQR9QT
FQR9Q+
FQR9Q7
```

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 1):

One of the answers on [this question](/q/42202/13154) suggests a tool that may be useful. I haven't tested it, but perhaps [Crunch wordlist generator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crunch-wordlist/) is able to do what you want.

Comment: There's a problem with this program. It replaces characters based on a mask. And the mask tells the nature of the replacement. But I would have to put two wilcards for one same letter. Ex: e may turn to E or 3. But the program only provides a way for testing with all lower case letters. or uppers or any number. But not a combination.
What I need are possible l33t combinations for a word.

Comment: @Sergio That's unfortunate. I only found this by searching, I have no idea if there are any programs that better suit your needs.